# Rspec - Testing an instance of a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm implemented a condition that if a user's email is not confirmed, they do not receive emails. My logic is, if the email isn't verified/ confirmed, return an instance of `ActionMailer::Base::NullMail.new`.

I wrote this test

```
 if @user.verified?
  next
 else 
  ActionMailer::Base::NullMail.new
 end 

 expect(TestMailer.test_mail(expired_account)).to be_an_instance_of(ActionMailer::Base::NullMail)
```

and the error I'm getting is

```
expected #<ActionMailer::MessageDelivery(#<ActionMailer::Base::NullMail:0x00007fb0f2f24090>)> to be a kind of ActionMailer::Base::NullMail
```

The question is, how can I re-write my test so that I can test that if the emails aren't verified they should return an instance of `ActionMailer::Base::NullMail.new`

Comment: I think you have to use `expect(TestMailer.test_mail(expired_account).message).to be.....`, you need to get the actual email object using the `message` method

Answer (score 3):

The error is telling you what the problem is right? You expect an instance of a mail type object, so change it to this. Also you should be able to use `be_a` method in place of `be_an_instance_of` in [Rspec see docs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/type-matchers)

```rb
expect(TestMailer.test_mail(expired_account).message)
  .to be_an(ActionMailer::Base::NullMail)
```

Comment: thank you! Just getting familiar with tests so this was super challenging for me.

Comment: @LindaKadz sure, this is slightly tricky because of the `.message` perhaps is not the most verbose name.

Comment: @LindaKadz can this be marked as "accepted answer" ?